# Trying to create a new Angular project from terminal and the following error is displayed

Tags: angular

```
⠹ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: angp@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"17.0.8" from @angular/forms@17.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!   @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/swaroopvontela/.npm/_logs/2024-01-02T14_33_38_824Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/swaroopvontela/.npm/_logs/2024-01-02T14_33_38_824Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

the log file contents are as following:

Log files:
/Users/swaroopvontela/.npm/_logs/2024-01-02T15_09_10_481Z-debug-0.log

> ## npm resolution error report
>
> While resolving: my-app@0.0.0
> Found: @angular/common@undefined
> node_modules/@angular/common
> @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project
>
> Could not resolve dependency:
> peer @angular/common@"17.0.8" from @angular/forms@17.0.8
> node_modules/@angular/forms
> @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from the root project
>
> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
> to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

using ng new

```
ng new appt             
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
? Do you want to enable Server-Side Rendering (SSR) and Static Site Generation (SSG/Prerendering)?
 Yes
CREATE appt/README.md (1058 bytes)
CREATE appt/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE appt/.gitignore (548 bytes)
CREATE appt/angular.json (2728 bytes)
CREATE appt/package.json (1257 bytes)
CREATE appt/tsconfig.json (903 bytes)
CREATE appt/tsconfig.app.json (324 bytes)
CREATE appt/tsconfig.spec.json (273 bytes)
CREATE appt/server.ts (1703 bytes)
CREATE appt/.vscode/extensions.json (130 bytes)
CREATE appt/.vscode/launch.json (470 bytes)
CREATE appt/.vscode/tasks.json (938 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/main.ts (250 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/favicon.ico (15086 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/index.html (290 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/main.server.ts (264 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.component.html (20884 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (910 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.component.ts (362 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.config.ts (321 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.routes.ts (77 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/app/app.config.server.ts (350 bytes)
CREATE appt/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
⠋ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: appt@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"17.0.8" from @angular/forms@17.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/forms
npm ERR!   @angular/forms@"^17.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/swaroopvontela/.npm/_logs/2024-01-02T15_34_01_704Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/swaroopvontela/.npm/_logs/2024-01-02T15_34_01_704Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above
```

log report:

```
0 verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@10.2.5
2 info using node@v20.10.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 1ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/Users/swaroopvontela/Desktop/angular_prac/appt/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:file:/Users/swaroopvontela/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 11ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
18 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 1ms
20 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
21 verbose title npm install
22 verbose argv "install" "--ignore-scripts"
23 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 25ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 1ms
```

Comment: "For a full report see: `/Users/swaroopvontela/.npm/_logs.....`"  Did you have a look at those files? And what was not clear about that?

Comment: here are the log details. it does not point to a specific error:
14 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load Completed in 7ms
16 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 7ms
17 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms

Comment: Stackoverflow invented an [edit] option (just below your question). This option is available to improve your question, because code in a comment is not formatted, and therefore not readable.

Comment: Try using `npx @angular/cli@latest new my-app`

Comment: npx @angular/cli@latest new my-app produced the above log. not useful

Comment: Can you provide more details?  I am not able to reproduce this, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4vQq.png

Comment: @luuk can you see the last part where it begins with ng new <appname>

Comment: @apopis44: Sorry, on my linux machine `ng` is starting some Emacs editor, ...... Will take too much time to figure out how to fix that 

Comment: Successful created project there was a problem with initializing git i guess. ✌

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're encountering issues with package dependencies while working with a package manager, possibly npm. The flags --force and --legacy-peer-deps are typically used to override certain checks or force the installation of packages even if there are dependency conflicts.
Clear npm cache:
npm cache clean --force
Remove node_modules and package-lock.json:
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json
Install again:
npm install
Use --legacy-peer-deps flag:
npm install --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: i have tried using --force and --legacy-peer-deps it displayed the following message:

Answer (score -1):

@apopis44 I think you forgot to send the message

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).